# What is the easiest way to work with Google Docs API in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-docs-api

What is the easiest way to work with the Google Docs API in a Ruby on Rails application? Is there a gem  available?

I did find this page: [Google Data on Rails](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html), is it the most up to date resource?

Answer (score 9):

The google data rails on page is really out of date, at least in a ruby 1.9.3 environment its non useful.

Having a play with the google_drive gem now....

https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby#readme

I was able to get it to work by simply installing it and pasting the readme code into a file.  What more can you ask for!?

Answer (score 4):

You can also Bearer universal API client available in Ruby.

This way you can query Google Docs API very easily and don't even have to worry about OAuth or refresh tokens: https://www.bearer.sh/integrations/33/google-docs-api

Answer (score 2):

The Google Docs developers have now released their own gem to work with the API. Here's a guide to getting started: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ruby

And the gem itself can be downloaded in the normal way from Rubygems: `gem install google-api-client`

There's more information in the Readme for the gem's source code repository: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client

Answer (score 0):

you can use this gem [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2). Make configuration with consumer-key and secret-key. Add gem in Gemfile. Follow github.